# Check if string (between // and /) contains a colon and a dot

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is between `//` and `/`, ie. `{sub1}//{string}/{sub2}`

How can I tell (possibly the fastest way) if this string contains both a colon (one or more) and a dot (one or more)? For example:

```
testsomething//apple:phone./hello -> TRUE (string contains both a colon and a dot)
test1//apple:phone/someth -> FALSE (string doesn't contain a dot)
worl//apple:::ph. one/hello -> TRUE (string contains a colon and a dot)
som//:app.le-phone/thing - TRUE (string contains a colon and a dot)
kor//.apple phone/sor - FALSE (string doesn't contain a colon)
len//:.applephone/fbe - TRUE (string contains a colon and a dot)
bei//apple.phone.:/sse - TRUE (string contains a colon and a dot)
dfsd//apple:phon:e/dsd - FALSE (string doesn't contain a dot)
```

Comment: `explode()`, `strpos()`, `preg_match()` ... what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried strpos, but it doesn't check all combinations (string may be different)..

Comment: once you have the \\ to \ segment, you would use strpos twice once for dot once foe colon

Comment: Yes, so probably script should first find {string}, ie. text between // and / and then check if a colon and a dot exists..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pure strpos attempt

```
$str="worl//apple:::ph. one/hello";

$x=explode('/',$str); //extract your substring, your examples are regular its always $x[2]

$findme   = '.';
$pos = strpos($x[2], $findme);

$findme   = ':';
$pos2 = strpos($x[2], $findme);

if ($pos !== false && $pos2 !== false) {
echo 'its a bingo'; 
}else{
    echo 'no bingo';
}
```

Comment: The only thing I'm worried about is that `/` may not always be followed by `/` so if there was `some/word //stuff:here./` you will get some issues. Which is why I recommended regex.

Comment: @A.Lau it works on all the OP's examples - cant do any more than that, i could proved a string to break your **regular expression** :-)

Comment: true enough, can't prepare for everything from a few examples.

Comment: @Tom 10 million loops, strpos(15.1 seconds) preg_match(15.9 seconds) - your results may well not match mine.

Answer (score 2):

Use preg_match as follows:

```
$string = "testsomething//apple:phone./hello";

preg_match("/\/\/((.*?[:].*?[.].*?)|(.*?[.].*?[:].*?))\//", $string, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Since you don't care about the order of `:` or `.`, `[:]` and `[.]` is put before and after.

The `\/\/` delimits to `//` and `.*?` is a non-greedy catch all.

Edit:

updated the regex from `preg_match("/\/\/(.*?[:.].*?[:.].*?)\//", $string, $match);` to `preg_match("/\/\/((.*?[:].*?[.].*?)|(.*?[.].*?[:].*?))\//", $string, $match);` as the previous one would match anything if it had double `:` or `.` as well. This will only match if both colon and full stop are present, and not if either one is missing.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess strpos is not good here or would be slower?

Comment: @Tom in general `strpos`, would always be faster than `preg_match`. but due to the multiple steps required, you would need to benchmark it

Comment: I think strpos would just involve A LOT more code, since you're checking for a lot of stuff. Also mark as answer if it's the right one, thanks :)

Comment: You would have to check the first `/` then the next `/` and see if it's directly next to it. If it's not, then you keep checking and what not. Then you'd have to check for both `:` and `.` and make sure its' between the starting and ending of the substring.

Comment: Makes sense - going back by tomorrow and I think your answer is going to work well. Will publish result then, thanks.

Comment: You need another set of parentheses to isolate the alternation.  Right now it matches `//:.` (trailing `/` irrelevant) **or** `.:/` (leading `//` irrelevant).

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks.

Comment: even slower now :-)

Comment: @nogad but regex is less prone to errors as you don't have to do as much coding :D